# External js function in ejs file

Tags: javascript, html

I have `home.ejs` file, I need to add char on my page so I add external js file into my footer part of my code:

```
<script src="demo/superuser-chart.js"></script>
```

I added my chart in superuser-chart.js file, if I use without function it works and I show the chart. But when I use in the function and call from home.ejs it couldnt work.
This is chart it function from `superuser-chart.js` file:

```
   function chartIt(){
  console.log("chart calling")
// Area Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("superUserChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
      }]
  },
  options: {
      scales: {
          y: {
              beginAtZero: true
          }
      }
  }
});

}
```

And I call the home js like this:

chartIt()

It doesnt work, also I cant see console.log output. When I check the console error log from browser I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: chartIt is not defined`
How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: chartIt is not defined` means you are calling your function before the `<script src="demo/superuser-chart.js"></script>` is loaded.You need to load the script first then call the function.Add `<script src="demo/superuser-chart.js"></script>` in header before calling the function